# Is this attempt at a definition of an invariant Laplacian valid for non-Euclidean spaces?

Tags: tensors, laplacian

I am studying Tensors from Ref 1. After the introduction of the invariant expression for the gradient of a scalar field $F$ , I tried coming up with an expression for the Laplacian. (This was very early on, even before the introduction of elementary concepts like the covariant derivative)

$$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial Z^j}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z^i} \vec{Z}^{\,i} \right)\right)\cdot \vec{Z}^{\, j}$$

The argument I used to justify to myself that this works (at least in Euclidean spaces) is that since it is an invariant (between coordinate systems) and reduces to the correct form in Cartesian coordinates it should work in all coordinate systems that describe Euclidean space because of the tensor property.

However, I would like to know if this attempt (if valid) can be used for non-Euclidean spaces where I can't simply assume reduction to the correct form in Cartesian coordinates implies validity for all coordinate systems as Cartesian coordinates may not even exist.

References:

1. *Pavel Grinfeld - Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces*

Comment: What exactly is $\frac{\partial}{\partial Z^j}$ acting on? Everything to its right? I think you'll find that this doesn't transform like a tensor. You also should know that there is a well defined laplacian on general manifolds, which is, up to a sign, $(d + \delta)^2$ where $d$ and $\delta$ are the differential and co-diffrential respectively.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins it only acts on the parenthesis. I will edit it to make it clear. It should transform as a tensor right? Because essentially we have a derivative of an invariant vector field (gradient of $F$) dotted with the contravariant basis.

Comment: You've got a second derivative, which usually spoils invariance. This is why, for example, $[X, Y]$ is a vector field, but $XY$ is not. But don't take my word for it. Try to write this expression down in a different coordinate system and see what happens. It will probably be a good exercise.